# A controller with this name is not registered and Routing is not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Below is my code:

Home.html and List.Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head >
    <title>AngualrJS Controller</title>
</head>
<body >

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="AddController.js"></script>
    <script src="ListController.js"></script>
    <script src="RouteController.js"></script>

    <a href="#!list">List</a>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

List.html

```
<div ng-controller="ListController">List </div>
```

Below is HomeController.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

ListController.js

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope) {

});
```

Below is routerconfig.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Home.html",
        controller: "myCtrl"
    })

    .when("/list", {
        templateUrl: "List.html",
        controller: "ListController"
    })
});
```

When I click on List page link is gives below error

> "A controller with this name is not registered."

Comment: have you included     <script src="ListController.js"></script>
 in list.html too?

Comment: Can we see your $routeProvider?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale, I have included ListController.js in Home.html not in List page.

Comment: please include that in list.html too.

Comment: @F.Almeida, Please see routeProvider which I have added in my question.

Comment: @Hitesh why are you overwriting an app every time `var app = angular.module(...)`?

Comment: agree with @AlekseySolovey, yes please avoid that too

Comment: in html you have <a href="#!list">List</a> i.e - !list, but in routing checking with only /list. i think missing '!' character.

Comment: need to modify <a href="#!list">List</a> with <a href="#/list">List</a>
will work fine.

Comment: I think you are overwriting your app route config before declaring controllers. Try to remove the app.module declaration before the controller definition.

Comment: @OmprakashSharma OP has the right syntax for angularjs 1.6

Comment: Did you load `routerconfig.js`. I can't see this in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Routing dependency will go only with myApp.

Home Controller ::

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

& routerconfig.js::

```
angular.module("myApp").
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Home.html",
        controller: "myCtrl"
    })

    .when("/list", {
        templateUrl: "List.html",
        controller: "ListController"
    })

});
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote 3 times

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

remove from ListController.js and from routerconfig.js

write one time into Home Controller in this way:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```